# Create hierarchy via MDX in Excel

Tags: excel, set, mdx, pivot-table

I am trying to add a new dimension to an OLAP Cube in Excel via the Set-Manager MDX.

The sets I have defined are as follows:

```
{[All].[Camp 2].&[024],[All].[Camp 2].&[035],[All].[Camp 2].&[043]} = Indirect
{[All].[Camp 2].&[026],[All].[Camp 2].&[034],[All].[Camp 2].&[042]} = Direct
```

This creates a new dimension in the OLAP Cube but it does not allow me to have both sets as filters. Instead I need a hierarchy "Campaign" which is a new dimension and consists of the hierarchy members "Indirect" and "Direct" as defined above.

Is that possible via MDX in the Set Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Adding new `Dimension` requires changing cube architecture:

1. You have to define dimension source, key column and attribute relationships
2. You have to define hierarchies
3. You have to define dimension processing, storage mode and many other parameters
4. You have to modify existing SSAS roles to allow/deny dimension data access

This can only be done via XMLA scripts or SQL Server Data Tools for VS. Also, hierarchy != dimension.

Please be more detailed.